# oauth access token by authorization header when POST

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0

Is it possible to receive the access token by header (POST) exactly like when DELETE meaning:

```
 Authorization :  Bearer 08712391237918273192873token
```

Instead of:

```
 {     
    access_token : 08712391237918273192873token
 }
```

My server implementation is:

```
 $storage = new OAuth2\Storage\Pdo(array(myconfig));
 $server = new OAuth2\Server($storage, array(
   'always_issue_new_refresh_token' => true,
   'refresh_token_lifetime'         => 2419200,
));

$server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\ClientCredentials($storage));
$server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\AuthorizationCode($storage));
$server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\RefreshToken($storage));

if (!$server->verifyResourceRequest(OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals())) {
    $server->getResponse()->send();
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as you an see in the code at https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/blob/develop/src/OAuth2/TokenType/Bearer.php#L63 the server will try to obtain the token from the header, the query parameters or the post body (in that order) and it will make sure only one of those methods is used at a time.

Comment: let see if I understand well, said this, it should not make any changes and it should work perfectly only passing the parameters via Header, but if that's the case is not working. Any guessing?

Comment: I am using bshaffer and sending the token in header as bearer , the issue is when I am using method POST that time it's authenticating the token correctly but for the same code if I am using GET that time it's not authenticating and throwing error token is expired  @andresmijares25